# Upload pdf file using Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, http, file-upload, laravel-5

I'm using Laravel 5.2 and I want to make a form which can upload a pdf file with it. I want to add that file on folder "files" in "public" folder. 
 
here is my view:

```
<div class="form-group">
     <label for="upload_file" class="control-label col-sm-3">Upload File</label>
     <div class="col-sm-9">
          <input class="form-control" type="file" name="upload_file" id="upload_file">
     </div>
</div>
```

and what should I do next? what should I add in my controller and route?

Comment: Did you tried to read documentation first? https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/requests#files

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First you should add `enctype="multipart/form-data"` to your `<form>` tag. Then in your controller handle the file upload as follow:

```
class FileController extends Controller
{
    // ...

    public function upload(Request $request)
    {
        $uniqueFileName = uniqid() . $request->get('upload_file')->getClientOriginalName() . '.' . $request->get('upload_file')->getClientOriginalExtension());

        $request->get('upload_file')->move(public_path('files') . $uniqueFileName);

        return redirect()->back()->with('success', 'File uploaded successfully.');
    }

    // ...
}
```

[Link to Laravel Docs for Handling File Uploads](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/requests#files)

Laravel casts the file type params in request to `UploadedFile` objects. You can see Symfony's `UploadedFile` class [here](https://github.com/symfony/http-foundation/blob/master/File/UploadedFile.php) for available methods and attributes.

Comment: you have to use $request->file

Answer (score 4):

First of all, the documentation tells you exactly what to do [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/requests#files).

What you want to do is adding this to your `<form>` tag:
`enctype="multipart/form-data"` (This allows you to upload data), set a `method`(get/post) and an `action` (url).

Then you want to set up your routes.

For example:
`Route::post('/pdf/upload', 'FileController@upload');`

This way you make sure that when you send the form it will go to your `FileController` with `upload` as function.

In your controller you want to declare the file as explained in the docs.
`$file = $request->file('photo');`.

From this point you can do whatever you'd like to do with the file (`$file`). For example uploading it to your own server.

Answer (score 3):

```
  public function store(Request $request)
  {
        if($request->file('file')) 
        {
            $file = $request->file('file');
            $filename = time() . '.' . $request->file('file')->extension();
            $filePath = public_path() . '/files/uploads/';
            $file->move($filePath, $filename);
        }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You Could Use Simple Method It Can Save The File

```
$path = $request->file('avatar')->store('avatars');
```

For More Information [Here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/filesystem#file-uploads)

Answer (score 1):

you can this code for upload file in Laravel:

```
 $request->file('upload_file')->move($path,$name);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at how i upload files, all files are accepted:
first the code for the create.blade.php form

```
{!! Form::open(
   array(
     'url' => 'uploads',
     'method' => 'post',
      'class' => 'form',
      'novalidate' => 'novalidate',
      'files' => true)) !!}

     @include('uploadspanel.create_form')
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

Remember to set files to true

Then the uploadspanel.create_form

```
<div class="form-group">
    {!! Form::label('name', 'Name:') !!}
    {!! Form::text('name', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    {!! Form::label('file', 'Bestand:') !!}
    {!! Form::file('file',null,['class'=>'form-control']) !!}
</div>

@if(\Auth::user()->level == 2)
    <div class="form-group">
        {{ Form::label('approved', 'Beschikbaar voor:') }}
        {{ Form::select('approved', array(1 => 'Iedereen', 2 => 'monteurs', 3 => 'concept'), null, ['class' => 'form-control']) }}
    </div>
@else
    {{ Form::hidden('approved', 3) }}
@endif

<div class="form-group">
    {!! Form::submit('Bestanden uploaden',['class' => 'btn btn-primary form-control']) !!}
</div>
```

then the controller store function

```
public function store(UploadRequest $request){
        $extension = Input::file('file')->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $filename = rand(11111111, 99999999). '.' . $extension;
        Input::file('file')->move(
          base_path().'/public/files/uploads/', $filename
        );
        if(\Auth::user()->level == 2) {
            $approved = $request['approved'];
        } else {
            $approved = 3;
        }
        $fullPath = '/public/files/uploads/' . $filename;
        $upload = new Uploads(array(
            'name' => $request['name'],
            'format' => $extension,
            'path' => $fullPath,
            'approved' => $approved,
        ));
        $upload->save();
        $uploads = Uploads::orderBy('approved')->get();
        return view('uploadspanel.index', compact('uploads'));
    }
```