# Call to a member function getClientOriginalName() on null laravel

Tags: php, laravel, file-upload

I keep on getting this error when I try to upload a pdf document file, does anybody have any idea how to solve this?

I had tried looking for similar problems but still can't solve it(eg: [Upload pdf file using Laravel 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36715776/upload-pdf-file-using-laravel-5))

I tried doing `dd()` to see if the file have been uploaded and it did show the file name but the error said `Call to a member function getClientOriginalName() on null`, so now I'm kind of confused on what to do now.

Here are my codes, thanks in advance for helping.

Controller:

```
 class CreateController extends Controller
{
    public function create(){

    return view('create');
}
public function store(Request $request){

  $uniqueFileName = uniqid() . $request->get('upload_file')->getClientOriginalName() . '.' . $request->get('upload_file')->getClientOriginalExtension();

   $request->get('upload_file')->move(public_path('files') . $uniqueFileName);
//dd($request);
   return redirect()->back()->with('success', 'File uploaded successfully.');
}
```

create.blade.php

```
   <form  enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="{{ url('/user')}}">

             {{  csrf_field()  }}
          <div class="form-group">
     <label for="upload_file" class="control-label col-sm-3">Upload File</label>
     <div class="col-sm-9">
          <input class="form-control" type="file" name="upload_file" id="upload_file">
     </div>
</div>


 <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-6-offset-2">
              <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Save">
            </div>
          </div>
</form>
```

Route:

```
Route::get('/user/create','CreateController@create');
Route::post('/user','CreateController@store');
```

Comment: you want `$request->file('upload_file')`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use the `file()` function to have access to your uploaded file

`$request->file('upload_file')`

Comment: do  a `var_dump($request->file('upload_file'))` and paste the info here

Comment: Wait, sry, actually it worked, tks a lot, i need to change all of the get() to file()

Comment: @blastme yes you do, see more info at:https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/requests#retrieving-uploaded-files

Comment: Is there anyway to view the pdf file by any chance? @madalinivascu

Comment: where do you want to view it?,if on the page you will need a object/iframe

Comment: Like, can I convert it back to a normal pdf file, becoz after uploading it became some weird file

Comment: like maybe retrieve the original file back

Comment: your file should be the same file uploaded, just with a diffrent name

Comment: Because after uploading the name of the file became php55B9.tmp, I find it weird as I also thought it should be the same name as the original file

Comment: the server automatically renames your file for security reasons, you can rename it back to the original name or you can let laravel give it a unique name

Comment: Oh I see but how do I do that, do you have maybe any resources for it?

Comment: follow the link i provided you have all the info there

Answer (score 8):

This enctype solved function call on the null problem

```
<form method="" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but as far as I can see, the thread owner already uses `enctype="multipart/form-data"`.

Answer (score 2):

use this code in your tag form `enctype="multipart/form-data"`

```
<form method="" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Comment: this is the problem in my case. I forgot to include the enctype attribute in my form. +1

Answer (score 1):

Try to put the file into a var.

```
$file = $request->file('upload_file');
```

And get the extension and name from it.

```
 $uniqueFileName = uniqid() . $file->getClientOriginalName() . '.' . $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

The key to solving this problem is that you must write `getClientOriginalName()` function in the `if` clause just like that:

```
if($request->hasFile('logoImage')){
    $logoImage = $request->file('logoImage');
    $name = $logoImage->getClientOriginalName();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if($request->has('sound_file')) {
            $image = $request->file('sound_file');
            $filename = $image->getClientOriginalName();
            request()->$image->move(public_path('images/users'), $filename);
            $sounds->image = $request->file('sound_file')->getClientOriginalName();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  if ($request->hasFile('file')) {
        $thumbnail = $request->file('file');
        $thumbnail = $thumbnail->getClientOriginalName();
      
    }
```