# Viewed 31k times 1 1 i tried to upload profile picture pict but i got error "Call to a member function getClientOriginalName() on null"

Tags: laravel-5

This my categories controller with resource controller

[image]

i got this error

> "Call to a member function getClientOriginalName() on null"

Comment: Welcome, can you please not post code as images but as text and maybe explain a little more what you're trying to achieve and what goes wrong? Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and 
[How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: You viewed 31k times regrading this problem ? why ? i got this in 1st google search in first attempt.....here is your solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/46885349/4650866